# Solving T(n) = T(n-1)*T(n-2)

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

So, this is how I solved

$\displaystyle
        T(n-1) \approx{}  T(n-2)
    $

$\displaystyle
        T(n) = T(n-1)^2
    $

Add log in both sides

$\displaystyle
        log(T(n)) = 2log(T(n-1))
    $

$\displaystyle
       Let\:\: log(T(n)) = S(n)
    $

$\displaystyle
S(n) = 2(S(n-1))
    $

We know that from Fibonacci series

$\displaystyle
S(n) = O(2^n)
    $

$\displaystyle
log(T(n)) = O(2^n)
    $

$\displaystyle
(T(n)) = O(2^{2^n})
    $

Ok, so where did I go wrong here??

Comment: 1) You seem to be after _solving a recurrence_ for function $T$, not analysing a recursive algorithm called T. 2) You're using $=$, $\approx$, and $= O$ a little willy nilly. Try deriving sandwich recurrences, i.e. $T_l(n) \leq T(n) \leq T_u(n)$, given by recurrences you can solve. If $T_l \in \Theta(T_u)$, you've won.

Comment: Be very careful using this "log on both sides" thing. It does _not_ always work! See our reference questions [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2789/98) and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/98) for related reading.

Comment: Taking logarithm on both sides _immediately_ would have been so simple and led directly to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

> So, this is how I solved
> $T(n-1) \approx{}  T(n-2)$
> $T(n) = T(n-1)^2$

An equality is the most precise and most powerful entity in the world. Please treat it with due respect.

Let me show how wrong it is if you use approximation liberally with equalities. If your argument above is sound, we can also do the following.
$\quad T(n) \approx{}  T(n-1)$
$\quad T(n-1) = T(n-1)*T(n-2)$
$\quad T(n-2) = 1$  if $T(n-1)$ is not 0.
So $T(n)$ must be 0 or 1 from time to time . That is obviously false, however.  For example, we can let $T(1)=T(2)=2$.

---

#### What to do?

What you can do is, as gnasher729 suggested, "taking logarithm on both sides immediately", assuming $T(1)>0$ and $T(2)>0$, which can be assume generally when we are analyzing recurrence relations in computer science.

You can also, of course, dive into analysis by cases when $T(1)$ and $T(2)$ might be 0 or even negative.